# C# WMI hyper-v add VHD to "IDE Controller 0" after creation

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I am able to create a VM in Hyper-V called "LON-DEV-01", but now I want to add the VHD "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Learning\10175\Drives\LON-DEV-01.vhd" to IDE Controller 0 as the main drive.

I have managed to set the machines memory to 8192 and Processors to 4, but here I am stumped.

Been searching for hours but getting nowhere fast.

Comment: I have looked at the post for "Programmatically attaching a VHD to a remote Hyper-V VM", but what is the <ideControllerPath>, <syntheticPath>?